# Overflow hidden not working on tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have an `overflow:hidden` on the `div` containing the tooltip but this one is not hide outside the `div`.
The tooltip is displayed on hover of the images and follow the movement of the mouse.

Here the link to the page : http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/works/

HTML

```
<div class="tooltipbloc" style="margin-top:<?php the_sub_field('top_gauche'); ?>%">

  <a id="tooltip" data-tooltip="<p style=font-
size:24px;font-family:founders_grotesk;margin-bottom:0px;text-
transform:uppercase><?php the_title(); ?></p>"
href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

  <div class="img-container">
     <div class="hover-thumb background-thumb"></div>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
  </div> 

  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tooltipbloc{
   position:relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
var moveTooltip = false,
  $tooltip = $("<div/>", {
    appendTo: "body",
    id: "tooltip",
    css: {
      position:"absolute",
      display:"none",
      width:500,
      textAlign:"center",
      padding:10,
      color:"black",
      fontSize:24,
    }
  });
```

Comment: what's the css for the tooltip id? a#tooltip{ ????}

Comment: It's displayed in JS, I just added it to the post.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but what's the value of top gauche?? (It's much easier if you paste the HTML output!!!.. the source of .. I mean)

Comment: Did you inspect the tooltip when it is popped up? Are you 100% sure that your tooltip is in your container block? The js says it is appended to the body... `appendTo: "body"`

Comment: Top-gauche is the value define in admin of margin-top.
I can't inspect the tooltip in chrome, it doesn't appear. The JS code said "body" but it hapenned to each post hover. I put the link of the page, will be easier.

Comment: Link to the page : http://tmp.thomasdesnoyers.com/works/

Comment: @tomdes did you view the source of your page? many of the divs simply have margin-top:% (no value behind the percentage sign, not even a 0!) Please do not post links. In future, make a fiddle using https://www.jsfiddle.net (or jsbin.com) AND include an excerpt of the un-working code in your question (that includes ALL relevant css, you have omitted many classes here), html and js. Welcome to the site Help us help you!

Comment: @Rachel Thank you, the site is still in preprod so I just need to hide the margin-top if empty. I will try to make better post next time.